# Identifying correct html nodes and css selectors to use with rvest or RSelenium

Tags: rvest, rselenium

I would like to complete a more advanced web scraping exercise to get data from a [webpage](https://www.property24.com/for-sale/fourways-gardens/sandton/gauteng/5857/110846340/).

I would like to use either `rvest` or `RSelenium`, but I am unable to make the correct connections between how to identify the data correctly on the page to pass through to my code.

On this specific page, I would like to get the following data into a data frame:

[image]

[image]

What is the easiest way to identify the correct html nodes / css parameters to use in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider something like this :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")

url <- "https://www.property24.com/for-sale/fourways-gardens/sandton/gauteng/5857/110846340/"
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_1 <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]")
text_1 <- web_Obj_1$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text_1, "\n")[[1]][1 : 15]
 [1] "R 5 400 000 Bond Costs"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [2] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [3] "4 Bedroom House for Sale in Fourways Gardens"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [4] "Fourways Gardens, Sandton"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 [5] "Contact agents for street address"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [6] "4"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [7] "3"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [8] "3"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [9] "900 m²"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[10] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[11] "Chic urban lifestyle!"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[12] "A classy, stylish, open plan modern home with all the luxuries! A calm ambience, a place to relax and enjoy positioned close to all the amenities of the Fourways Gardens Lifestyle Estate. This home exudes elegance throughout and has ducted air-con keeping an even temperature through the home. The covered patio area is unique and private with a sparkling pool and minimalist garden, ideal for the executive family. The lounge and dining room are very spacious and they are open plan to a stunning modern kitchen. The kitchen is a lovely combination of walnut and cream gloss cupboards and cream caesarstone tops and fitted appliances, including a coffee machine, two ovens and a built in microwave. The gas hob is interactive with the large breakfast bar making this a social space. The scullery is spacious and there is direct access to the fabulous triple garage. The family..."
[13] "Read More"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[14] "Bedrooms: 4"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[15] "Bathrooms: 3"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 
web_Obj_2 <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]")
text_2 <- web_Obj_2$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text_2, "\n")[[1]]
[1] "Bedrooms: 4"  "Bathrooms: 3" "Garages: 3"   "Pet Friendly" "Pool"         "Garden"       "Study"       
 
web_Obj_3 <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="js_accordion_propertyoverview"]/div')
text_3 <- web_Obj_3$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text_3, "\n")[[1]]
 [1] "Listing Number"   "110846340"        "Type of Property" "House"            "Listing Date"     "22 February 2023" "Erf Size"         "900 m²"           "Floor Size"      
[10] "472 m²"           "Levies"           "R 2 940"          "Pets Allowed"     "Yes"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 
web_Obj_4 <- remDr$findElement("css selector", 'body > div.p24_theme > div.p24_listing.p24_regularListing > div.container.p24_content > div > div > div.p24_listingContent > div.p24_listingCard.js_bondCard > div.p24_bondCalculator')
text_4 <- web_Obj_4$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text_4, "\n")[[1]]

[1] "Bond Calculator"                           "Purchase Price"                            "R"                                         "Deposit (Optional)"                       
 [5] "R"                                         "Interest Rate"                             "%"                                         "Loan Term"                                
 [9] "20 years"                                  "Monthly Repayment:"                        "R 56 659"                                  "Total Once-off Costs:"                    
[13] "R 534 149"                                 "Min Gross Monthly Income:"                 "R 188 866"                                 "View Breakdown"                           
[17] "What do I qualify for based on my income?" "What are the bond and transfer costs?" 

web_Obj_5 <- remDr$findElement("id", '153487942')
text_5 <- web_Obj_5$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text_5, "\n")[[1]]

[1] "A classy, stylish, open plan modern home with all the luxuries! A calm ambience, a place to relax and enjoy positioned close to all the amenities of the Fourways Gardens Lifestyle Estate. This home exudes elegance throughout and has ducted air-con keeping an even temperature through the home. The covered patio area is unique and private with a sparkling pool and minimalist garden, ideal for the executive family. The lounge and dining room are very spacious and they are open plan to a stunning modern kitchen. The kitchen is a lovely combination of walnut and cream gloss cupboards and cream caesarstone tops and fitted appliances, including a coffee machine, two ovens and a built in microwave. The gas hob is interactive with the large breakfast bar making this a social space. The scullery is spacious and there is direct access to the fabulous triple garage. The family..."
[2] "Read More"
```